# Maximum Flow algorithm. How to prove the following statements

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

Good Evening,

So I am trying to solve this exercise which is a paticular case of maximum flow algorithm. Here the graph must have all even edges and 1 odd edge and it must have a maximum flow that is odd.

Now I need to prove the following two points which state that the single odd edge must have a flow $>1$ and/or that edge must have maximum flow in it with respect to its capacity.

I understand that running certain algorithms to find odd flow in such cases prove that both statements are correct that is there is a flow $>1$ in odd edge and also there is maximum flow always in that odd edge. But I don't know how to prove it formally.

Question text:

Consider a graph $G=(V,E)$, with integer capacities on the edges, such that for all $e\in E\setminus\{e^∗\}$, it holds that $c_e$ is an even number, and $c_{e^∗}$ is odd. Suppose that there is a maximum flow in this graph with odd flow.

a. Prove/Disprove: It must be that in every maximum flow, there is a flow in $e^∗$ (i.e., $f_{e^∗}>0$).

b. Prove/Disprove: It must be that in every maximum flow, there is a full flow in $e^∗$ (i.e.,$f_{e^∗}=c_{e^∗}$).

[image]

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: I am sorry, I have added the question in text as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Max-flow/Min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) can be used to prove this property.

As a reminder, $f$ is a max-flow if and only if there exists a cut $X$ of capacity $|f|$.

Let $f$ be a max-flow of odd value in $G$.

a. Suppose there is no flow through $e^*$. Then in $G[V\setminus\{e^*\}]$, $f$ is still a max-flow. However, since all edges have even capacity, all cuts have even capacity. Contradiction.

b. The same idea can be used, I will let you try to find the details.

Comment: So what I can understand and by running some example network flows., is that the cut must have a one edge as odd capacity. and since there will be odd capacity in the cut, the max flow will be odd since cut flow = max flow.

and because odd edge will be one of the edges of the cut, it will have the max flow itself. 

Is that correct?